# Overlap multiple images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a **image object composed of 3 images**.

**Final picture how it should look like**
[image]

There is **one text image** and **two "gear" images**.

Why I want to split them you ask? I want to implement a scrolling function which spins the gears of the image when scrolling down the page.

Later on I want that image object to **be always on top at the left corner**. Thats why I choose **relative position**. Cause the gears always have to stay relative to the text.

I got the function already but somehow **Im having problems stacking the images onto eachother**.

Thats how it currently looks like.

**Current state**
[image]

```js
function rotate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  rot += e.deltaY * 0.5;
  leftGear.style.transform = `rotate(${rot}deg)`;
  rightGear.style.transform = `rotate(${rot}deg)`;
}


let rot = 0;
const leftGear = document.querySelector(".leftGear");
document.body.onwheel = leftGear.onwheel = rotate;
const rightGear = document.querySelector(".rightGear");
document.body.onwheel = rightGear.onwheel = rotate;
```

```css
/* To make white images become visible */
body { background: #161924 }

.nav-logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.rightGear {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.leftGear {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.leftGear img {
  display: block;
}

.rightGear img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-logo" style="display: block">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSCDm.png" height="60">
  <div class="rightGear" id="rightgear">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6541L.png" height="40">
  </div>
  <div class="leftGear" id="leftgear">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6541L.png" height="40">
  </div>
</div>
```

[gearText.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSCDm.png) (It has some blueish background so it doesn't overlap the wrong sections)

[gear.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6541L.png)

Comment: could you share the individual components of the image so i can try doing this in a way that's responsive?

Comment: You could try `position: absolute ` on the classes of the images you would like to stack.

Comment: Added the images.

Comment: share your all image files to get perfect solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can play with absolute position and z-index here.**

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.nav-logo {
  position:relative;
}
.rightGear {
  position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.leftGear {
      position: absolute;
    bottom: 6px;
    right: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav-logo" style="display: block">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSCDm.png" height="60">
      <div class="rightGear" id="rightgear">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6541L.png" height="30">
      </div>
      <div class="leftGear" id="leftgear">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6541L.png" height="30">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the first image into another div then make all of your positions absolute.  Here's an example

```css
.nav-logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.rightGear {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.leftGear {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.leftGear img {
  display: block;
}
.rightGear img {
  display: block;
}

.main{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-logo" style="display: block">
      <div class="main">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" height="60">
       </div>
      <div class="rightGear" id="rightgear">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" height="40">
      </div>
      <div class="leftGear" id="leftgear">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" height="40">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle I made using the images you added pretty much getting exactly what you want. You'll of course need to make 2 different "gear" images with with their separate part then orientate it like how I did. https://jsfiddle.net/68t5o3zp/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just move those gears with position properties, depending on what you need. Also the gears are under the main logo, so they should have lower z-index than the main logo.

Also change the height of each gear from 40 to 30.

```css
body {
  background: #161924
}

.nav-logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.rightGear {
  position: relative;
  top: -52px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: -2;
}

.leftGear {
  position: relative;
  top: -69px;
  left: 27px;
  z-index: -2;
}

.leftGear img {
  display: block;
}

.rightGear img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-logo" style="display: block">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSCDm.png" height="60">
  <div class="rightGear" id="rightgear">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6541L.png" height="30">
  </div>
  <div class="leftGear" id="leftgear">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6541L.png" height="30">
  </div>
</div>
```